# app is not working properly when run on 2 devices simultaneously (React Native / MongoDB)

Tags: react-native, mongodb-query, expo

I have a strange issue>
I have built an app and when I run it on my iPad (Expo Go), all works fine. But when I run it on my iPhone, it gives an error message from Nodejs.

I am trying to get data from a MongoDb database.
this is the code I use to connect to the backend:

```
axios.post('http://192.168.0.224:8000/findMessage', {lastMessageId: lastMessage})
```

lastMessage is an existing value.

this is at the backend-side:

```
messages.find({_id: req.body.lastMessageId}, {message: 1})
```

on iPad is it running as it should, it returns a value.
But as soon as I run the exact same code on my iPhone, I get this error message at the backend-side:

```
'reason: BSONError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters or an integer'
```

how come it works on iPad and not on iPhone? Both are on the same iOS.
I already removed and reinstalled Expo Go but the same issue.
Starting the server with 'npm start --reset-cache' also does not solve this.

Anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thx,
Peter

edit:
if I console.log(lastMessage) before the axios function, it gives the correct one. But it isnt passed to the backend, only an empty string is passed.

edit2 (maybe important): it only happens when I run the app on both devices at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> edit: if I console.log(lastMessage) before the axios function, it gives the correct one. But it isnt passed to the backend, only an empty string is passed.

> axios.post('http://192.168.0.224:8000/findMessage', {lastMessageId: lastMessage})

I think you are trying to search a "message" with the message ID but you pass in parameter the whole message object, maybe try something like

```js
axios.post('http://192.168.0.224:8000/findMessage', {lastMessageId: lastMessage.id})
```

Comment: No, that was not the issue cos it works fine. The issue is that it only happens when the app is running on 2 devices simultaneously (I just figured that out). Run only on iPad: ok, run only on iPhone: ok. But on these 2 devices at the same time … that error messages comes up (on one device)

Comment: New edit … it is not related to be running on 2 devices at the same time. After hours of testing I found out it was just a big coincidence. The error message sometimes appears (let’s say in 10% of the times I runnit), the other times it runs fine. Probably a small but annoying issue in my backend-code (something with promises)